# Snippet MarkerOptions in Android Studio to be in front of everything

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I am using Google Maps in Android Studio, and adding marker with snippet using markeroptions. The snippet box (with title and address information) supposed to appear when tapping at the marker. But the snippet box appears to be behind my search text box (TextView), button, etc.

**Can someone please help me on how to put this snippet box to be in front of everything in the layout when appeared?** The picture is attached below, you can see the snippet box highlighted with red box.

FYI, I made a separate layout to create a custom snippet box.

Thank you for your help!

[Picture of snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0kA9.png)

Comment: can you share the layout

Comment: I added the picture in the original post. Thank you!